# Dep ensure hangs infinetely

Tags: go, dependencies

When I run

```
dep ensure -v
```

on VSCode Editor's Terminal, it prints the following messages as shown in the screenshot and then shows no message after that for infinite time. I wondered if it is doing something in the background, but the Activity Monitor shows dep consuming 0% CPU. It has been like this for an hour now. There was a

```
(0) select root
```

option, so I pressed 0 and hit Enter. Do I need to do something ? Has it happened for anyone else ? I am using macOS Mojave. I am new to Linux, Golang and dep. I installed dep using

```
brew cask install dep
```

[image: screenshot_vscode_terminal]

Comment: I believe dep doesn't support interactive GIT login. Are you using interactive git login?

Comment: what is your go version?

Comment: @Joao version is go1.12. Dep ensure was stuck because I didn't have access to a repository. After I took the access, it worked. It doesn't print any message about failed authorization though.